# date column validation

Tags: date-time

Is it possible to validate the end date to be not greater than by 30 days over the start date? So if the Start Date is February 18, the End Date cannot be more than 30 days past February 18. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- Click the List Settings button on the List tab of the Ribbon.
- Under General Settings, click the Validation Settings link.
- Type a formula in the Formula text box.

  =DATEDIF([START DATE], [END DATE],"d")<= 30
- The result of the formula must evaluate to TRUE to pass validation. The formula syntax is the same as calculated columns, which is similar to Excel syntax.
- Enter a user message that you want to appear if the validation formula fails.
- The message should give the user an idea of how the formula works and how to fix the problem.
- Click the Save button.